# Finding source of logo slider

Tags: css, animation, slider

I seen this logo slider on a lot of websites and i need help to either locate where to get it or any ideas to make it.

I tried to look through the sourcecode and can't how it is made.
I guess it is some sort of plugin or theme but not sure?

Example of one of the websites: https://www.webfx.com/